# confirm() results return different results from console.log()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, prompt

[image: different results]

[image]

as you can see prompt returns false and when you press ok console.log prints true. I was really confused how did that happened? does prompt reads, they do not have the same letter reason why it returns false? and console returns true coz they have the same type?

Comment: you output two different things, why you are surprised ?

Comment: you would use `alert` instead of `confirm`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of a `confirm` is not based on your expression you pass into it. It is based on what button the user clicked. So, while `'y'==='n'` will always be `false`, the `confirm` will return true if the OK, button is clicked.

```js
console.log(confirm("If you click OK, 'true' is returned. If you click Cancel, 'false' is returned. What's returned has nothing to do with the value you pass to the confirm() method. That is simply the data to be displayed in the dialog."));
```

Comment: yep no worries i just need to cool it down after 5 mins left thanks again Scott